# Convergence and upper bound of $\sum_n \frac{\sin\left[\left(\pi-\frac{1}{4}\right)(x_n-x_m)\right]}{x_n-x_m}\sin\left(\frac{x_n+x_m}{4}\right)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to study the convergence of the series:
$$\sum_n \frac{\sin\left[\left(\pi-\frac{1}{4}\right)(x_n-x_m)\right]}{x_n-x_m}\sin\left(\frac{x_n+x_m}{4}\right)$$
where $x_n$ is a sequence of real numbers. Is possible to find a condition on $|x_n\pm x_m|$ for which this series converges? In this case, what is its upper bound?

Comment: What's the role of $m$? Is $x_m$ constant?

Comment: Yes, it is fixed.